# Reading from microphone to .wav

Tags: javascript, arrays, wav

I'm reading from a microphone and saving the recordings in a .wav file.I have done lots of research and this is what came best solution:
 [link](http://typedarray.org/from-microphone-to-wav-with-getusermedia-and-web-audio/)

My question is what does the 44 in

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + interleaved.length * 2);
```

corresponds to.

What I have understood to that point is that we created a Buffer where the recordings are saved to i Byte format.But what is the 44 corespond to and why `interleaved.length*2` although the interleaved corresponds to both channels left and right???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the format of the data. The ArrayBuffer is used to store raw Bytes. 
This question is about the [WAV format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)

The 44 bytes are for the header looking like this:

```
writeUTFBytes(view, 0, 'RIFF');              //Magic word identifying the stream (4 bytes)
view.setUint32(4, 44 + interleaved.length * 2, true); //Size of stream in bytes (4 bytes)
writeUTFBytes(view, 8, 'WAVE');              //Another magic word (4 bytes)
// FMT sub-chunk
writeUTFBytes(view, 12, 'fmt ');            //format header (4bytes)
view.setUint32(16, 16, true);               //4 bytes size of format  (16 bytes)
view.setUint16(20, 1, true);                //2 bytes audio format
// stereo (2 channels)
view.setUint16(22, 2, true);               //2 bytes apparently number of channels
view.setUint32(24, 44100, true);           //4 bytes sample rate
view.setUint32(28, 44100 * 4, true);       //4 bytes byte rate
view.setUint16(32, 4, true);               //2 bytes block align
view.setUint16(34, 16, true);              //2 bytes bits per sample
// data sub-chunk
writeUTFBytes(view, 36, 'data');           //'data' == 4 bytes
view.setUint32(40, interleaved.length * 2, true);
```

Then we come to the actual data which is interleaved.length of Int16 that is 2 bytes per item..

```
// write the PCM samples
var lng = interleaved.length;
var index = 44;
var volume = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++){
    view.setInt16(index, interleaved[i] * (0x7FFF * volume), true);
    index += 2;
}
```

Comment: thank you that was helpful what about (0x7FFF * volume)?what does it mean?

Comment: You should mark the question to be about the WAV format.. 
0x7FFFF is 2^15-1. 
This is bit manipulation on the data in interleaved probably to increase volume.. I'm guessing it is a fixed point math trick to avoid using floating point math

Comment: I have been trying to search for a website that describes in details the description of this code but I can't find, if you can help me with any, for example what does the functions merge and interleave do??

Comment: I added a link to the WAV specification. Also the W3Org specification (in the article) https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html
The interleave and merge are explained in the article..